# How to expose a docker machine to an internal network

Tags: networking, docker, jenkins, docker-swarm

I've created a docker container 
And I tried a lot of methods to expose it to my internal network by :

1-Bridging the lan connection on my docker VBox machine but had no luck

2-Bashing into the container itself and  binging any machine within the network Worked fine but opening the /etc/hosts file showed an IP which is different from My containers ip (I don't know how)

I'm using  docker toolbox :

Client:

Version:      17.03.1-ce

API version:  1.27

Go version:   go1.7.5

Git commit:   c6d412e

Built:        Tue Mar 28 00:40:02 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:

Version:      17.04.0-ce

API version:  1.28 (minimum version 1.12)

Go version:   go1.7.5

Git commit:   4845c56

Built:        Wed Apr  5 18:45:47 2017

OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Experimental: false

My container is Jenkins

Comment: Can someone help please

Comment: Anyone can help??